# Can Armorer Artificers make magic armor into Power Armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, unearthed-arcana, artificer

Can [Armorer Artificers](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/UA2020-Subclasses03_0224.pdf) make armor that is already magical (e.g. Armor of Invulnerability) into Power Armor?

Comment: @gto No it doesn’t, the chest piece of the magic armor contains the magic while the rest become infusable

Comment: Armor Modification doesn't seem terribly clear to me on that point, but I see how you could interpret it like that and I prefer your interpretation, so I withdraw my comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Yes

If the feature could only affect non-magical armor it would say so. As it stands it says

> you can turn a suit of heavy armor you are wearing into power armor

Magical heavy armor is still heavy armor.